# Simple delphi capturing keys does not work when integrated into a project

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010

This simple capturing keys works fine as standalone VCL project

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, DBCtrls, DBCGrids, Db, DBTables, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FLastMsg: TMsg;

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  capturedWord:string;
implementation

{$R *.DFM}

function GetCharFromVirtualKey(Key: Word): string;
 var
    keyboardState: TKeyboardState;
    asciiResult: Integer;
 begin
    GetKeyboardState(keyboardState) ;

    SetLength(Result, 2) ;
    asciiResult := ToAscii(key, MapVirtualKey(key, 0), keyboardState, @Result[1], 0) ;
    case asciiResult of
      0: Result := '';
      1: SetLength(Result, 1) ;
      2:;
      else
        Result := '';
    end;
 end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var i,j:integer;
begin

  if ((GetAsyncKeyState(13) and 1) = 1) or ((GetAsyncKeyState(32) and 1) = 1) then begin;
      capturedWord:='';
      exit;
  end;
  For i:=32 to 128 do begin;
    if ((GetAsyncKeyState(i) and 1) = 1) then begin;
      capturedWord:=capturedWord + GetCharFromVirtualKey(i);
      capturedWord:=LowerCase(capturedWord);
       label1.Caption:=      (capturedWord);

      end;
    end;
  end;

end.
```

But when I integrate it into my project, it captures chinese or no-sense keys !

Any idea why ?

[image]

Comment: What's different between the two projects?

Comment: I'm surpriced to see that it is allowed to put a semicolon after begin!

Comment: @LURD why not? It's just a statement separator.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes, but I cannot recall ever seeing it in 28 years of pascal programming. Not even typing it by mistake.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Your test code works fine, and you've provided no information (or code) about how you "integrate it into" your project. Obviously, there's something wrong with how you "integrate it into your project", but as you've provided no information about that, it's extremely difficult to offer help. @LURD: The code compiles, but from a readability and maintenance standpoint I agree - the placement of the `;` after the `begin` is horrible.

Comment: final project have some JVC components: I cannot understand what is wrong.

I think 
asciiResult := ToAscii(key, MapVirtualKey(key, 0), keyboardState, @Result[1], 0) ; gives that erro

Answer (score 1):

Your approach does not make sense.

`WM_TIMER` messages are low priority. If the message queue holds higher priority messages the WM_Timer messages will not get through.

Ever since Windows 1 there is no need for polling to get keys.
It will only get fragments of input.

**Don't poll for keys**
It's better to drop the timer approach and use a OnKeyPress in the form.
If you want to capture all keys OnKeyDown is the way to go.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Self.KeyPreview:= true;  (*-- all keypresses get send to the form as well.*)
end;

//Takes dead keys into account
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                             virtual key code.
begin
  case Key of 
    32: if Shift = ssShift then .....
end;

//Just shows the char pressed.
procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  case Key of .....
end;
```

See the online help for more info.

Besides, polling for keys is a poor approach anyway it kills battery on laptops because it prevents the system from going to sleep. If you wait for a key* event your system can go to sleep, preserving battery.

Comment: Looks like malware, hence the polling. The poor man's key logging solution.

Comment: I think guy is trying to implement keyboard hook that awful way, not just monitoring keys in own app.

Comment: Does Windows 7 still allow you to capture global keyboard input? Don't you need root-privileges for that?

Comment: I think : 
asciiResult := ToAscii(key, MapVirtualKey(key, 0), keyboardState, @Result[1], 0) ;

gives the error